# Does scala perform optimisations in chained functions?

Tags: list, scala, performance

```
val list1 : List[String] = List(....)
val list2 : List[String] = List(....)
val filtered = list1.filter(list2.toSet.contains)
```

When using the code above, will `toSet` be called for each item in `list1` (in which case I should add another `val set2 = list2.toSet`, or does the Scala compiler optimizes this in which case the code above will only run `toSet` once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no optimizations needed, `toSet` can only run once:

1. [eta-expansion rules](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#eta-expansion-section) for converting `list2.toSet.contains` to a lambda. In this specific case the translation is

   ```
   list1.filter({
     val x1 = list2.toSet
     { (y1: String) => x1.contains(y1) }
   })
   ```
2. the argument to a method is evaluated before calling it (except for call-by-name parameters, but this isn't one), and to evaluate this block `val x1 = list2.toSet` is executed first and then `{ (y1: String) => x1.contains(y1) }` is returned.

But of course you can be more explicit if you want.

Comment: @texasbruce I didn't check but if it doesn't this would be a bug (if I understand the specification correctly).

Comment: Will this change of instead of `filter(list2.toSet.contains)` it would a function literal like `filter(x => list2.toSet.contains(x))`, or with additional logic `x => list2.toSet.contains(x) && x != "baaa"`

Comment: @TheDude Yes, this will evaluate `toSet` every time the lambda is called because it's inside the lambda body now. Here optimizations _would_ be required to avoid it. You can try compiling with `-optimize` (see https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/compiler-options/index.html) and then look at the bytecode to check if it worked, but I would be slightly surprised if it did.

Comment: With `//print<TAB>` in the REPL you can see that this is exactly (except for the names) the desugaring that the compiler does.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure it is called once, you can just do:

```
val list1 : List[String] = List(....)
val list2 : List[String] = List(....)
val s: Set[String] = list2.toSet
val filtered = list1.filter(s.contains)
```

Having said that, you can use [`intersect`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/StrictOptimizedSeqOps.scala#L89) method:

```
list1.intersect(list2)
```

This method is located on a trait called `StrictOptimizedSeqOps`, and it has comment in its implementation: `// Avoid multiple map lookups` So I guess this is optimized.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question

Comment: I don't think this check does what you want it to; if Scala had simpler eta-expansion rules and expanded `list2.toSet.contains` to `(x: String) => list2.toSet.contains(x)`, it would still output `hey` once but call `list2.toSet` once per `list1` element.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I see. Thanks. I rolled back to my previous answer which doesn't assume anything about the eta expension.